# ASP.NET Core Identity without the UserName

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Is there a way to use ASP.NET Cores Identity system without making use of the `UserName` and without reinventing the wheel?

I'm working on a project which doesn't require a UserName, and I've just been setting it to a GUID for the moment so I can work around it, but it's a bit of a hack, and not very clean in my opinion.
The only alternative I've found is to implement a custom `UserManager<TUser>`, `IUserStore<TUser>`, but that's quite a fair bit of work for such little gain, and it'll be difficult to keep up with ASP.NET Cores changes over time.

If there aren't any alternatives, is there a reason ASP.NET Cores `IdentityUser<TKey>` class has a `UserName` property, as opposed to just keeping things bare bones?

Comment: What's unique to a user then? If it's their email, you can put email as username.

Comment: The current implementation of Identity 2.2 sets the Username equal to the email. So, no, you do not need to use Username. It almost seems like username will be going away.